# basic QNetworkAccessManager fails to send requestion

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

There is no error in my code though there is never any request packet hits my server. I run tcpdump port 80 and nothing ever crosses the wire, wireshark says the same.

//coreeng.h

```
#ifndef COREENG_H
#define COREENG_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class coreEng : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
        public:



        private slots:

        public slots:
            void connect();
            void url();
            void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply);


        private:
            QNetworkAccessManager* nam;

};

#endif // COREENG_H
```

//coreengine.cpp

```
#include "coreeng.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImageReader>

coreEng::coreEng(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

explicit coreEng(QObject *parent = 0)
    {
        nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    }

void coreEng::connect(){
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void coreEng::url(){
    QUrl url("http://www.myserver.com");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void coreEng::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply){

    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);

    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {

        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
        QImage pic = imageReader.read();

        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
        QString string(bytes); // string
    }

    else
    {

    }

    delete reply();

}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "coreeng.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    coreEng mConnect;
    mConnect.connect();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `coreEng::url()` so you never make a request.

I'm also not sure your constructors are correct.  Why not just ditch the explicit constructor and create the QNetworkAccessManager in the default constructor?